# NHibernate 3.3 Right Join QueryOver One-to-One Relationship

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql, queryover

So, this is the situation. I have a C# project that uses NHibernate 3.3 (upgrading is not an option), with the following classes:

```
public class Person{
    public List<PersonAddress> PersonAddresses {get;set;}
}

public class NaturalPerson : Person{
    public NaturalProperty NaturalProperty {get;set;}
}

public class LegalPerson : Person{
    public LegalProperty LegalProperty {get;set;}
}

public class Quarantine{
    public Person QuarantinePerson {get;set;}
    public QuarantineProperty QuarantineProperty {get;set;}
}
```

What I need to do is to obtain Persons that may or not "be in quarantine" and that satisfy different conditions that involve Quarantine's properties, and legal or natural properties. Basically what I need is a Left Join from Persons, or a Right Join from Quarantines:

```
Select *
From Quarantine q
Right Join Persons p on p.ID = q.QuarantinePersonID
Left Join NaturalPersons np on p.ID = np.ID
Left Join LegalPersons lp on p.ID = lp.ID
Where q.Property = 1
and np.Property = 1
```

This is what I have now. I have managed to do the "from" clause that I need, but I'm having serious problems with the "select" and "where" clauses:

```
Person p = null;
Quarantine q = null;
var results = this.Session.QueryOver<Quarantine>(() => q)
                  .JoinQueryOver<Person>(() => q.QuarantinePerson, () => p, JoinType.RightOuterJoin)
                  .SelectList(list => list
                     .Select(() => p.Id))
                  .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<Person>())
                  .List<Person>();
```

This code generates the following query:

```
`SELECT p1_.PersonID as y0_
FROM   BUP.Quarantines this_
       right outer join BUP.Persons p1_
         on this_.QuarantinePersonID = p1_.PersonID
       left outer join BUP.LegalPersons p1_1_
         on p1_.PersonID = p1_1_.PersonID
       left outer join BUP.NaturalPersons p1_2_
         on p1_.PersonID = p1_2_.PersonID`
```

As I said, the "from" clause is OK. Now the problem is with the Select and Where clauses.

The main problem with the Select is that I need the whole Person object, wether it's a legal or a natural person. I have tried removing the .SelectList from the query, but it throws a PropertyNotFoundException: "Could not find a setter for property 'p' in class 'Person'".

And the problem with the Where clause is that i don't know how to add conditions based on NaturalPerson and LegalPerson's properties. I have no problem filtering Quarantine and Person properties, but haven't yet succedeed to do the same with the other classes.

Also, this query should be as performant as possible, because timeout is a serious problem. I have managed to do other solutions with subqueries and such, but they took too long.

Any help, with any of the two issues, will be very appreciated!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **subqueries** mixing with **future** to execute both queries in one row trip:

```
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Quarantine>()
    .Select(x => x.QuarantinePerson.Id);

var naturalPersons = Session.QueryOver<NaturalPerson>()
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Id).NotIn(subquery)
    //.Where(x => x.NaturalProperty == somehing)
    .Future();

var legalPersons = Session.QueryOver<LegalPerson>()
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Id).NotIn(subquery)
    //.Where(x => x.LegalProperty == somehing)
    .Future();

var persons = naturalPersons.Cast<Person>().Union(legalPersons);
```